# minesweeper in C not writing down an output

Tags: c

I am new at this website and please excuse any wrong use that i might have done in this question.

I tried to design a minesweeper with a input `*.dat` file. dat file contains the number of rows and columns of the matrix and the coordinates of the mines. I have to show the mines by using '*' and the distance of every cell to the mine. I wrote something like this but i get no output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int nr, nc;

void mine_setting( char [nr][nc] );
void show_grid( char [nr][nc] );
void coordinate_evaluation( char [nr][nc], short, short );

int main( void ) 
{


char grid[nr][nc];

mine_setting( grid );
show_grid( grid );
return 0;
}

void mine_setting( char grid[nr][nc] ){
int i, j;
FILE*inStr;
inStr=fopen("minspos.dat","r");
fscanf(inStr, "%d %d", &nr, &nc);

//array creation
for( i=0; i < nr; i++){
    for( j=0; j < nc; j++ ){
        grid[i][j] = '0';
}
}


// mine grid
for( i=0; i < nr; i++ ){ 
    for( j=0; j < nc; j++){

        fscanf(inStr, "%s",grid[i][j]);
        grid[i][j]='*';

        if( grid[i][j]=='*' ) 
            coordinate_evaluation( grid, i,j ); 
}       
}



fclose(inStr);
}

void coordinate_evaluation( char grid[nr][nc], short x, short y ) {
// -1,-1
if( x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0 && grid[x-1][y-1]!='*' ) 
    grid[x-1][y-1]++;
// -1,0
if( x-1 >= 0 && grid[x-1][y]!='*' ) 
    grid[x-1][y]++;
// -1,+1
if( x-1 >= 0 && y + 1 < nc && grid[x-1][y+1]!='*' )
    grid[x-1][y+1]++;
// +1,-1
if( x+1 < nr && y-1 >= 0 && grid[x+1][y-1]!='*') 
    grid[x+1][y-1]++;
// +1,0
if( x+1 < nr && grid[x+1][y]!='*' ) 
    grid[x+1][y]++;
// +1,+1
if( x+1 < nr && y+1 < nc && grid[x+1][y+1]!='*') 
    grid[x+1][y+1]++;
// 0,-1
if( y-1 >= 0 && grid[x][y-1]!='*' )
    grid[x][y-1]++;
// 0,+1
if( y+1 < nc && grid[x][y+1]!='*' ) 
    grid[x][y+1]++;

}

void show_grid( char grid[nr][nc] ) {
short i,j;
for( i=0; i < nr; i++) {
    for( j=0; j < nc; j++ ) {
        printf("%c ",grid[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
FILE*outStr;
outStr=fopen("neighbor.dat", "w");
for(i=0; i < nr; i++){
    for(j=0; j < nc; j++){
    fprintf(outStr, "%c", grid[i][j]);
}
}
fclose(outStr);             
}
```

Comment: So, personally, the best way to figure out what something like this is doing is to step through it with a debugger and check the variables are what they should be at each step. if you are using an ide it should have it built in; if not then if you are using gcc you can use gdb.

Answer (score 1):

You define the grid matrix *before* reading in the size, so it is probably set to 0,0 (technically it's undefined, but that's a separate issue).

You probably want to change grid to a pointer to a 2d array and after you read in `nr` and `nc` you should make an appropriate `(c/m)alloc` call to create the array (don't forget to `free` it afterwards!)

you are also mixing use of globals (nr,nc) and passed parameters (grid). This is okay, but if you are going to do this and you are going to alloc grid within mine_setting, then you will need to change it to take a pointer to grid.